How to migrate PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver to Swift 6 and Strict Concurrency Checking?
I have the following code:
extension AssetGridViewController: PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {
    func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
        Task { @MainActor in
            guard let changes = changeInstance.changeDetails(for: fetchResult) else { return }
            fetchResult = changes.fetchResultAfterChanges
        }
    }
}

With Swift 6, this generates a compilation error: Main actor-isolated instance method 'photoLibraryDidChange' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement. The error includes to fix-it suggestions:

Adding nonisolated to the function (nonisolated func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange))
Adding @preconcurrency to the protocol conformance (extension AssetGridViewController: @preconcurrency PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {)

Both options generate a runtime error: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x105b7c400). For context, AssetGridViewController is a regular UIViewController.
Any ideas on how to fix this?
Edit: Sample project https://github.com/tovkal/PhotoSwift6

Did you try nonisolated func… and MainActor.assumeIsolated { instead of Task { @MainActor in?

That also crashes with EXC_BREAKPOINT

Does it crash, or merely pause execution? I might suggest going to the breakpoint navigator in Xcode and disabling breakpoints, if any.

It is a runtime crash, not a breakpoint. If you run the app without Xcode it crashes. I have added a link to a sample project, in case somebody wants to try it.
